# Reactor Flux flatMap operator throughput/concurrency control and achieve backpressure

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive-streams, spring-webclient

I am using Flux to build my reactive pipeline. In the pipeline, I need to call 3 different external system REST APIs, which are very strict with their Rate of access. 
I will be throttled exponentially if i breach the rate-per-sec threshold. Each system will have their own thresholds.

I am using Spring WebClient to make the REST API calls; among 3 APIs, 2 of them are GET and 1 is POST.

In my reactor pipeline, the WebClient are wrapped within the flatMap to perform the API calls, like the below code:

```
WebClient getApiCall1 = WebClient.builder().build().get("api-system-1").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class) //actual return DTO is different from string
WebClient getApiCall2 = WebClient.builder().build().get("api-system-2").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class) //actual return DTO is different from string
WebClient getApiCall3 = WebClient.builder().build().get("api-system-3").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class) //actual return DTO is different from string

    Flux.generator(generator) // Generator pushes the elements from source 1 at a time

    // make call to 1st API Service
    .flatMap(data -> getApiCall1)
    .map(api1Response -> api1ResponseModified)

    // make call to 2nd API Service
    .flatMap(api1ResponseModified -> getApiCall2)
    .map(api2Response -> api2ResponseModified)

// make call to 3rd API Service
.flatMap(api2ResponseModified -> getApiCall3)
.map(api3Response -> api3ResponseModified)

// rest of the pipeline operators

//end
.subscriber();
```

The problem is, if I dont set the `concurrency` value to the flatMap, then I the pipeline execution breaching the threshold within few seconds of service startup.
If I set the value of `concurrency` to 1, 2, 5, 10, then the throughput is becoming very low.

**The Question is, Without setting any value to the concurrency How could I achieve the Backpressure which should honour the rate limits of the external system?**

Answer (score 12):

Given you have a "rate per second" requirement, I would explicitly window the flux and limit each window to the chosen time period. This will give you the maximum throughput without being throttled.

I would use a helper function similar to:

```
public static <T> Flux<T> limitIntervalRate(Flux<T> flux, int ratePerInterval, Duration interval) {
    return flux
            .window(ratePerInterval)
            .zipWith(Flux.interval(Duration.ZERO, interval))
            .flatMap(Tuple2::getT1);
}
```

which allows you to do:

```
sourceFlux
        .transform(f -> limitIntervalRate(f, 2, Duration.ofSeconds(1))) //Limit to a rate of 2 per second
```

You can then map this as necessary onto your `WebClient` calls while respecting the limit in place for each API:

```
sourceFlux
        //...assume API 1 has a limit of 10 calls per second
        .transform(f -> limitIntervalRate(f, 10, Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
        .flatMap(data -> getApiCall1)
        .map(api1Response -> api1ResponseModified)

        //...assume API 2 has a limit of 20 calls per second
        .transform(f -> limitIntervalRate(f, 20, Duration.ofSeconds(1))) 
        .flatMap(api1ResponseModified -> getApiCall2)
        .map(api2Response -> api2ResponseModified)
```

...and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and example code @Michael Berry. One more question, I am going through the `Programmatically creating a sequence` section of this [Reactor 3 Reference doc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing), i see under generators no mention about Backpressure. However in Create I see Backpressure is supported. Does it mean, if I need backpressure support, I should use Create instead of Generate?

Comment: @NaveenKumar `generate()` is the ideal scenario from a backpressure perspective - the demand is wholly driven by backpressure. It thus doesn't require an overflow strategy, as an element isn't requested until it's explicitly prefetched. `create()` is essentially a wrapper for another API / source to emit any number of events arbitrarily as it wants to - so it's not explicitly backpressure-controlled, and therefore requires some form of overflow strategy to determine how to behave if the consumer can't keep up. `generate()` is thus almost always the preferable choice, if you can use it.

Comment: I missed an important point in my initial question. How does all this behave when I apply a scheduler `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())`? What I see is, the request rate is way to high when I apply a scheduler in my pipeline.

Comment: @NaveenKumar Not sure that should make a difference - I can't seem to produce it quickly. I'd start a new question for that, and make sure to include a [mcve].

Comment: If there are multiple sources (each flux per request) in that case the above mentioned code will exceed the number of request per second. How do we control this number of payments per second for multiple flux (multiple sources)

Answer (score 1):

Resilience4j has support for rate limiting with Reactor. 
See:

https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/ratelimiter

https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/examples-1#section-decorate-mono-or-flux-with-a-ratelimiter

Comment: Hi Martin Tarjányi, Thanks for pointers and Yes! indeed I am exploring them.